# Python 'break' says it is outside loop

Tags: python

When I run this python returns an error saying 'break is outside of loop' even when I mess around with the indentations. I have also tried adjusting with the gaps between lines even though this doesn't matter in python.  Please help!

```
# My guess the number game
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')

userName = input()
number = random.randint(1, 100)

print('Well, ' + userName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.') 
guess = input()
guess = int(guess)
guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')

if guess > number: 
        print('Your guess is too high.')

if guess == number:
    break

if guess == number:
  guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)

print('Good job, ' + userName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
  number = str(number)
print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: Looks like your indentation is off 1 level from `guess = input()` to the end of the program.

Comment: You have a `while guessesTaken < 6`. `print('Take a guess')` is inside the loop. Everything after that is outside the loop, because you haven’t indented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Python, spacing is what determines a code block. your `if` statements have the same indentation as `while`, so they are out of the loop.

also, you might want to `pydoc input`.

so after you fix the indentation and the wrong type of `input` statement, it works:

jcomeau@aspire:~/tmp $ python test.py

```
Hello! What is your name?
jc
Well, jc, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.
Take a guess.
5
Your guess is too low.
Take a guess.
66
Your guess is too low.
Take a guess.
88
Your guess is too high.
Take a guess.
77
Your guess is too high.
Take a guess.
74
Good job, jc! You guessed my number in 5 guesses!
```

[as Robᵩ pointed out in the comments, if it's Python3, `input` is correct.]

Comment: OP appears to be using Python3, so his usage of `input` is correct. Recall that Python2 `raw_input()` is equivalent to Python3 `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation was incorrect. Remember that in Python the content of a `while` or `if` is indented one level further than the `while` statement itself.

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')

userName = input()
number = random.randint(1, 100)

print('Well, ' + userName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break


if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + userName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Python indentation is mandatory because of it you left the loop before it should be,  your code should be like that :

```
# My guess the number game
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')

userName = input()
number = random.randint(1, 100)

print('Well, ' + userName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.') 
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')

    if guess > number: 
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + userName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```